# Will transferring an SVN repository dump from Linux to Windows cause EOL problems?

Tags: windows, newlines, subversion

I want to mirror an SVN repository on my local Windows system, but in order to save bandwidth I will have to do an svnrdump onto remote Linux system, zip it up and download it onto my Windows system.

Does the fact that the repository was first downloaded to a Linux system then transferrred to Windows mean there could be end of line conversion issues, as happens with Git systems which are not properly configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

No

**Longer answer**

EOL-problem is problem of Working Copies|working directories, not platform-independent repository storage. `svn:eol-style=native` **on every client** for all text/ types is answer for different client-side OS in SVN